# Regular Expression of given Automata

Tags: regular-language, deterministic

[image]

Can someone please help me in finding the regular expression for the given automata?
I know the basic steps of finding but in this question I'm stuck because in this case the initial and final states are same as well as their is a two parallel loops. 
I tried it by applying basic rules for finding regular expression but after some steps I'm stuck. Please help me in solving this. 
A new approach of finding would be appreciated. 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

hope u fine

i applied **"bypass/state elimination algorithm"**  on this DFA

after solving it out ..i retrive this RE maybe it looked some what like messy but yes you can check it out by testing different string .here it is

```
            1*+ (1*0(1)*0(0)*1).((01*0+1).(1)*(0(0)*1))*.0
```